# create table-space in PostgreSQL 12 by passing a string value. how to go about passing values to creating table-space using my custom values?

Tags: postgresql, tablespace

When I run the command below in PostgreSQL

```
CREATE TABLESPACE 'forex_eurusd_2020_07'
OWNER 'forex'
LOCATION 'f:\data\forex\eurusd\2020_07';
```

I get the following error.

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'forex_eurusd_2020_07'"
> LINE 3: CREATE TABLESPACE 'forex_eurusd_2020_07'
>                           ^
> SQL state: 42601
> Character: 21
> ```

***What I am trying to do here is to create table-space and later partition by passing the values in my function as string*** .
Though this is my test statement
Here is something else I tried below

```
do $$ 
declare
   tbl_spc varchar(50) := 'forex_eurusd_2020_07';
   forex_owner varchar(10) :='forex';
begin 
  CREATE TABLESPACE tbl_spc
  OWNER forex_owner
  LOCATION 'f:\data\forex\eurusd\2020_07';
end $$;
```

And got the following result

> ```
> ERROR:  CREATE TABLESPACE cannot be executed from a function
> CONTEXT:  SQL statement "CREATE TABLESPACE tbl_spc
>   OWNER forex_owner
>   LOCATION 'f:\data\forex\eurusd\2020_07'"
> PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 6 at SQL statement
> SQL state: 25001
> ```

In the end I am open to suggestions on how to go about passing values to creating table-space using my custom values?

Answer (score 0):

`'forex_eurusd_2020_07'` is an identifier so it needs to be double quoted(same with `OWNER` name). `quote_ident(string text)`([Docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-string.html)) is your friend. So:

```
quote_ident('forex_eurusd_2020_07')
```

The function issue is explained by the error:

`ERROR:  CREATE TABLESPACE cannot be executed from a function`

That is because [Tablespace](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createtablespace.html):

"CREATE TABLESPACE cannot be executed inside a transaction block."

And a function runs inside a transaction block. So you can't use a function for this.

Comment: I tried below :-
do $$ 
declare
   tbl_spc text := 'forex_eurusd_2020_07';
   forex_owner text :='forex';
begin 
  EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLESPACE '|| quote_ident(tbl_spc)
  || ' OWNER ' || quote_ident(forex_owner)
  || ' LOCATION ' || quote_literal('f:\data\forex\eurusd\2020_07');
end $$;

Got the following error:

ERROR:  CREATE TABLESPACE cannot be executed from a function
It generated the following string but failed to execute:-
......Contd......

Comment: It generated the following string but failed to execute:-
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "CREATE TABLESPACE forex_eurusd_2020_07 OWNER forex LOCATION E'f:\\data\\forex\\eurusd\\2020_07'"
Which when I ran without execute the generated it worked perfectly. But that is not the solution.
I think it does not support Execution of CREATE statement in functions. So what is the work around. I am trying to figure out

Comment: Well as I said above you cannot use a function for this. ```CREATE TABLESPACE``` is one of the commands that cannot run in a transaction(by extension a function). To mention some others, ```CREATE/DROP DATABASE``` and ```VACUUM```. If you want to do this you will need an external script.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by using python. As I was using python to get data which I was trying to post in a partitioned table with its own table-space. I was facing issues dynamically creating the table-space. Which I have achieved by writing the following in my code. I used  [the code given to create table](https://pynative.com/python-postgresql-tutorial/), instead of table, I modified to create the table-space.

```
connection = psycopg2.connect(user="forex",
                              password="MXXXXXX@XXXX",
                              host="127.0.0.1",
                              port="5432",
                              database="MyDB")
connection.autocommit = True
cursor = connection.cursor()

tbl_spc = 'forex_eurusd_2020_07'
forex_owner = 'forex'
location_tbl_spc = "'f:\\data\\forex\\eurusd\\2020_07'"
print(location_tbl_spc)
create_tbl_spc_query = ''' CREATE TABLESPACE  '''+tbl_spc+'''
OWNER  '''+forex_owner+'''
LOCATION '''+location_tbl_spc+''';'''
print(create_tbl_spc_query)
cursor.execute(create_tbl_spc_query)
connection.commit()
print("Table-space created successfully in PostgreSQL ")

except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
print("Error while creating PostgreSQL table-space", error)
```

`finally:`

## closing database connection.

```
if (connection):
    cursor.close()
connection.close()
print("PostgreSQL connection is closed")
```